# IE7/8 margin-bottom collapsing issue

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.marijevijselaar.nl/txp/media/), there are some margin-bottom problems:

[image]

It needs to look like this:

[image]

Every `<p>` has a `margin-bottom` of `21px`. It's probably a collapsing issue, but how do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the `span`-element inside the `p`-element has a negative margin:

```
#media .article p.voetnoot, 
#media .article span {
  margin-top: -21px;
  ...
}
```

In Internet Explorer the `audio`-element is replaced with an `object` nested inside a `span` and so the rule above is applied causing the media player to shift upwards:

```
<p>
  <span>
    <object ...
  </span>
</p>
<p class="voetnoot">...</p>
```

Try this instead:

```
#media .article p.voetnoot, 
#media .article p.voetnoot span {
  margin-top: -21px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... it does the trick. But ... how do you know? In the HTML source (IE7/8) I can't find the <span> and <object> tags!

Comment: I use Internet Explorer 9 and when the page has loaded I press **F12** to open the IE Developer Tools. With that I can inspect the HTML structure of the page. Some scripts may change the HTML, you will not see these changes using *View source*, but you will see these changes using the Developer Tools. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478